# How to deal with NA in a panel data regression?

Tags: r, na, predict, plm, panel-data

I am trying to predict fitted values over data containing `NA`s, and based on a model generated by `plm`. Here's some sample code:

```
require(plm)
test.data <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3), time=c(1,2,1,2,1), 
   y=c(1,3,5,10,8), x=c(1, NA, 3,4,5))
model <- plm(y ~ x, data=test.data, index=c("id", "time"), 
       model="pooling", na.action=na.exclude)
yhat <- predict(model, test.data, na.action=na.pass)
test.data$yhat <- yhat
```

When I run the last line I get an error stating that the replacement has 4 rows while data has 5 rows.

I have no idea how to get predict return a vector of length 5...

If instead of running a `plm` I run an `lm` (as in the line below) I get the expected result.

```
model <- lm(y ~ x, data=test.data, na.action=na.exclude)
```

Comment: This is handled since version 2.6-2 of plm, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702581/predict-out-of-sample-on-fixed-effects-model/71904457#71904457

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 2.6.2 of `plm` (2022-08-16), this should work out of the box: [Predict out of sample on fixed effects model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702581/predict-out-of-sample-on-fixed-effects-model/71904457#71904457) (from the NEWS file:

> prediction implemented for fixed effects models incl. support for argument `newdata` and out-of-sample prediction. Help page (`?predict.plm`) added to specifically explain the prediction for fixed effects models and the out-of-sample case.

---

I think this is something that `predict.plm` *ought* to handle for you -- seems like an oversight on the package authors' part -- but you can use `?napredict` to implement it for yourself:

```
 pp <- predict(model, test.data)
 na.stuff <- attr(model$model,"na.action")
 (yhat <- napredict(na.stuff,pp))
 ## [1] 1.371429       NA 5.485714 7.542857 9.600000
```

Comment: This is handled since version 2.6-2 of plm, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702581/predict-out-of-sample-on-fixed-effects-model/71904457#71904457