# How to change na.action for zero-inflated regression model?

Tags: r, plot, na, missing-data

I am running a zero-inflated negative binomial regression model using the function `zeroinfl` from the `pscl` package.

I need to exclude NA's from the model in order to be able to plot the residuals against the dependent variable later in the analysis.

Therefore, I want to set `na.action="na.exclude"`. I can do this without any problem for a non-zero-inflated negative binomial regression model (using `glm.nb` from the `glm` package), eg.

```
fm_nbin <- glm.nb(DV ~ factor(IDV) + contr1
               +contr2 + contr3, data=df, 
               subset=(df$var<500), na.action="na.exclude")
fm_nbin.res = resid(fm_nbin) 
plot(fm_nbin.res~df$var)
```

works fine. However, when I do the same for a zero-inflated model, it does not work:

```
zinfl <- zeroinfl(DV ~ factor(IDV) + contr1
               +contr2 + contr3 | factor(IDV) + contr1
               +contr2 + contr3, data=df, 
               subset=(df$var<500), na.action="na.exclude")
zinfl.res = resid(zinfl) 
plot(zinfl.res~df$var)
```

gives the error

```
Error in function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'df$var')
```

Is there any other command I should use to exclude NA's from my regression?

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427781/how-to-deal-with-na-in-a-panel-data-regression?rq=1) is the nearest of an answer I could find. Can it in some way be applied to my problem? 
Also, can `naresid` in some way be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both the option of using `na.omit(df)` or `na.action="na.exclude"` don't seem to work in a `zeroinfl` regression model, I found another (indirect)  way of achieving that `NA`'s are excluded in the regression.

First, since my original dataset contains far more variables than only the regressors and outcome variable, I created a new dataset including only the variables I use in the regression model; and also set a condition on the value of `var` to include observations in the regression:

```
df1 <- subset(df, var<500, select=c("DV", "IDV", "contr1", "contr2", "contr3"))
df1 <- na.omit(df1)
```

I then run the same code as above using the new dataset `df1`, which works perfectly:

```
zinfl <- zeroinfl(DV ~ factor(IDV) + contr1
           +contr2 + contr3 | factor(IDV) + contr1
           +contr2 + contr3, data=df1)
zinfl.res = resid(zinfl) 
plot(zinfl.res~df1$DV)
```

Comment: However, one needs unfortunately to repeat this procedure of defining a new dataset for each new regression model one wants to run, which can get cumbersome when using many different regression models.

Answer (score 1):

As one finds by following the trail of documentation from `zeroinfl` to `glm.fit`: "The ‘factory-fresh’ default is `na.omit`." Notice that I have not put quotes around it  since it is supposed to be a function rather but the function will accept it as a name so it doesn't matter if it is quoted. I will admit that I don't really know how `na.omit` and `na.exclude` really differ (something to do with residuals I read), but would definitely go with the default setting first, since it generally delivers what I want from regression functions. So try just leaving it out:

```
zinfl <- zeroinfl(DV ~ factor(IDV) + contr1
           +contr2 + contr3 | factor(IDV) + contr1
           +contr2 + contr3, data=df, 
           subset=(df$var<500) )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, just leaving na.exclude out does not work in my case. As found at ?na.exclude: "na.exclude differs from na.omit only in the class of the "na.action" attribute of the result, which is "exclude". This gives different behaviour in functions making use of naresid and napredict: when na.exclude is used the residuals and predictions are padded to the correct length by inserting NAs for cases omitted by na.exclude." -- This is why it is in my case crucial to take na.exclude instead of na.omit.

Comment: If you offer `na.omit(df)` as the data argument, the function should not see any NA's.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `na.omit(df)` in the data argument just gives the same error as using `na.action="na.exclude"`.