# Calculating ROC for panel data and Linear Probability Model

Tags: r, roc, panel-data, plm, economics

I have panel data from external assets of 102 countries over ~ 20-40 years, depending on the country.
I tried predicting the probability for a financial crisis, depending on log(total_liabilities to see whether an increase in foreign investment and other capital positions can help predict a crisis.

```
plm1 <- plm(crisis ~ log_total_liabilities + lag1_log_tot_lia + lag2_log_tot_lia + lag3_log_tot_lia
                        + factor(year) + factor(country), data = dt2, index=c("year", "country"), model="pooling")
summary(plm1)
```

I started by estimating a plm model, regressing on my crisis dummy.
To estimate the predictive ability, I wanted to generate a ROC and AUC value, given the regression

```
# Plot of True Positive Rate Against the False Positive Rate
pred1 <- predict(plm1)
pred2 <- prediction(pred1,as.numeric(plm1$crisis))
plot(performance(pred2,"tpr","fpr"), las=0, main="plm1")
```

I get errors like:

> Error: not fitting arguments / variables" (translated from German) or
> "all arguments/variables need to have the same length" (translated
> from German).

Another approach to obtaining Roc values would start with
When changing `pred1 <- predict(plm1, dt2)` (dt2 is my data frame, containing also some variables I had not used in the plm1 regression), the error differs:
The format of predictions is invalid. It couldn't be coerced to a list.

**Are PLMs simply not made for ROC calculations? And if so, how come that the paper attached presents AUROC values for a linear probability model with fixed effects? (See second last row)
And if no, what am I doing wrong?**

I attached the screenshot of the paper and my dataset.

[CSV File with datasat](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s4a1y7g9jddx0jp/AADU9aU7pumwFDIWDHNqlshYa?dl=0)

[Screenshot of paper with OLS AUROC value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKC3U.png)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904457/4640346 - it should work with the current development version of package plm.

Answer (score 0):

AUC-ROC only works for only binary classification problems. As you used a fixed effects regression, the predicted values produced after plm1, pred1, is a continuous one.